# What is this concept called bridging?

Tags: networking

What is this concept called bridging as in [Share the internet of one WiFi card through a hotspot of another WiFi card](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/659156/share-the-internet-of-one-wifi-card-through-a-hotspot-of-another-wifi-card?rq=1) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Bridge_with_netctl?

What is it used for?

Is it related to  packet forwarding as in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Internet_sharing?

Why is there no step for bridging in https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Internet_sharing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are bridges like hubs or switches?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430407/are-bridges-like-hubs-or-switches)

Answer (score 1):

For the concept and some general use cases, I suggest reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_bridge , which came up by searching https://en.wikipedia.org/ for "bridging", which links a page designated as "Bridging: Topics referred to by the same term".  Clicking on that link brings up a page for selecting the particular topic you want.  In this case it was listed as "Bridging (networking), a packet forwarding technique used in computer networks", which led to the above page.

Comment: thanks. I can't access the Internet freely under censorship

Comment: @Tim Google says there are 1.8 billions results for `network bridge`. I am sure you could have found at least one which would have explained it. You also have a rep of over 100k. You should know better.

Comment: @Bib I don't. ironically, Google is not accessible

Comment: @Tim, there is more than one search engine. I am sure even in your country, there are books & web sites available which would explain it. And if you can get to SE, then you should be able to find others. Good grief, even SE has a search option which you could have used.

Comment: @Bib How can you be sure that the available "search engines" are search engines? I don't make up the policy of earning reputations, if you think it is unfair.